# Chrome extension for blocking purpose

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a question about a chrome extension.

Can someone explain how to run a script in the background and block the URL that a visitor is trying to visit?

For example just intercept the visited URL and redirect the user to another website.

My manifest file correctly includes a file "background.js" but the file runs only when the user clicks on the extension icon.

I want my extension call a certain website before the page is loaded.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: For simple redirects it's best to use declarativeNetRequest: [info and examples](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/).

Answer (score 1):

You can define a rule to redirect a network request with the *declarativeNetRequest* API.

The redirection rule can be based on a url using the `urlFilter` property. The following rule catches urls matching the `google.com` filter and redirects them to `https://example.com`:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
        "type": "redirect",
        "redirect": { "url": "https://example.com" }
    },
    "condition": {
        "urlFilter": "google.com",
        "resourceTypes": [ "main_frame" ]
    }
}
```

See [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) API reference.